# How to lock a mesage in a webapp to prevent more than 1 user from editing it

Tags: java, sql, session, locking

I have a web application written in Java that allows users to send and reply to messages. These messages are stored in an SQL Server database. All messages belong to a user ID, but in some cases multiple users have access to the same ID (think one user with multiple email addresses, some shared with other users) so could potentially try to reply to the same message at the same time.

Solutions I have found all handle such scenario by checking if the message was modified before saving it. This is not feasible here because a) the reply is saved as a new record and b) I want to prevent a second user from even beginning a reply so they don't spend 30 minutes composing a reply just to then find out that someone else already replied to the message. Each message can only have one reply.

So to do that the message needs to be locked somehow. Then when user A starts to reply to a message a lock is placed on the message (say set a flag in the database record) and when user B now tries to reply to the same message he is informed that user A is already answering the message.

That's fine except that I'm dealing with a web app. So if for some reason user A while replying loses his session (say the browser crashes or whatever) the message will now remain locked.

My current solution for this is as follows:

- User A starts to reply to message X.
- A lock is written to another table with msg_id for message X, user_id for User A and session_id for user A's session.
- User B tries to reply to message X. The lock table is checked and B is informed he can't reply to the message because User A is already doing so (holding the lock).
- Now user A's browser crashes. User A logs back in and tries to access message X again. He is allowed because he is the one holding the lock. The session_id is updated to the new one.
- Now user A's browser crashes again. He is disgusted and goes on a 6 week vacation.
  Message X is now still locked by user A but the session eventually expires. An HttpSessionListener takes note when the session is destroyed and removes the lock.
  Finally user B can reply to the message.

Seeing that this last part of the scenario is, while possible, somewhat unlikely, this will probably work out fine.

I'd like to see if anyone has a better solution to this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario is pretty complete. But you can improve it by using AJAX.

The idea is to make a continous discussion between the server and the client by sending, let's say each minute, a flag from the client to the server to say "the client is writting a reply for the message X".

The server have to store the data in the database.

After that, the server have to use this date and hour value to eventually unlock the message if the delay is greater than expected.

In processing like that, your messages is no more locked 6 months, but only the delay fixed for the timeout.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing just that. I dropped the session id and instead write a timestamp that is updated every so often by an ajax call while a message is being answered. Works great.